# Best way to organize try-catch and try with resources in a function

Tags: java, exception

I have a piece of code where I am using try with resources for handling streams. I also have a line which calls a function which may throw an IOException.

Due to the way other business logic is organized, I do not want to make the function throw IOException. So far, this is what I've got -

```
try {
    final List<Map<?, ?>> data = readObjectsFromCsv(options.getInputFile());
    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream jsonEarningsData = writeAsJson(data);
        InputStream jsonData = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonEarningsData.toByteArray());
        InputStream csvEarningsData = new FileInputStream(options.getInputFile());)
    {
        final String key = join(UNDERSCORE, Arrays.asList(UUID.randomUUID(), formattedDate, options.getProgram()));
        final String jsonKey = join(EMPTY, Arrays.asList(key, EXTENSION_JSON));
        final String csvKey = join(EMPTY, Arrays.asList(key, EXTENSION_CSV));
        uploadFile(csvEarningsData, earningsDataBucketPrefix, csvKey);
        uploadFile(jsonData, earningsDataBucketPrefix, jsonKey);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Failure from File IO: ", e);
}
```

I however hate how this piece of code is organized and it seems overall ugly. I was hoping to get ideas on how to better model this piece of code.

EDIT: I separated out the data initialization from inside try-catch and wrote an inner method to handle the try with resources portion. This is what I came up with finally which is cleaner than the initial approach -

```
public void execute() {
    try {
        final File csvEarningsFile = options.getInputFile();
        final List<Map<?, ?>> data = readObjectsFromCsv(csvEarningsFile);
        uploadFileInitializer(data, csvEarningsFile);            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failure from File IO: ", e);
    }
}

private void uploadFileInitializer(List<Map<?,?>> data, File csvEarningsFile) throws IOException{
    final String key = join(UNDERSCORE, Arrays.asList(UUID.randomUUID(), formattedDate, options.getProgram()));
    final String jsonKey = join(EMPTY, Arrays.asList(key, EXTENSION_JSON));
    final String csvKey = join(EMPTY, Arrays.asList(key, EXTENSION_CSV));
    try (
        ByteArrayOutputStream jsonEarningsData = writeAsJson(data);
        InputStream jsonData = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonEarningsData.toByteArray());
        InputStream csvEarningsData = new FileInputStream(csvEarningsFile);
        ) {            
        uploadFile(csvEarningsData, earningsDataBucketPrefix, csvKey);
        uploadFile(jsonData, earningsDataBucketPrefix, jsonKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could separate declaration, initialization and usage of `data`. First delcare `data`. Then initialize it in a separate `try-catch`-block. After this block, write your `try-with-resources`-Block.

Comment: If you don't like the nested `try` blocks, you can refactor the inner into a separate method. The try blocks will still be nested in the callstack, just not in a single method. You need an outermost `catch` to handle IOExceptions that can be thrown from multiple places in the code. [Personal opinion - this method is short and understandable. The nested try blocks express exactly what you are trying to accomplish. There's nothing wrong with them.]

Comment: I tried both the approach. The first one led me to catch IOException in two places which was still messy. Overall, separating out the try with resources into an inner method and throwing IOException was way cleaner. Thank you! I'll add the refactored code as an edit for reference.